# How to build sliding horizontal menu. CSS

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to build a simple slider that consists of a static 'window' and movable list of items.

[image]

where parent container shows only one item and hides all the rest.
I've tried to do something like this but appears this is wrong:

```
<div id="category-selector">
    <div class="categories-list clearfix">
        <a class="category">sports</a>
        <a class="category">fashion</a>
        <a class="category">health</a>
    </div>
</div>

#category-selector {
    width: 300px; margin: 0 auto; position: relative; z-index: 1;
    border: 2px solid #ccc;
   -moz-box-sizing: content-box; -webkit-box-sizing: content-box; box-sizing: content-box; height: 55px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.categories-list {
    position: absolute; top: 0; left: 0; display: block;
}
a.category {
    display: block; float: left; width: 100%; padding: 10px;
    font-size: 30px; font-family: Cambria, 'Segoe UI', sans-serif; line-height: 35px;
    text-decoration: none; text-align: center; color: #42a6ce;
}
```

How do I achieve this functionality?

Comment: how do you expect to change between items?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
.categories-list {
    display: block;
    white-space: nowrap;

    /*margin-left: -300px;*/
}
a.category {
    display: inline-block; 
    width: 280px; 
    padding: 10px;
    font-size: 30px; font-family: Cambria, 'Segoe UI', sans-serif; line-height: 35px;
    text-decoration: none; text-align: center; color: #42a6ce;
}
```

If you want to have links arranged from left to right, you should set them fixed width. If you set 100% then they will always try to fill container. Setring `display` to `inline-block` allows us to avoid wraping line by setting `white-space: nowrap;` on container.
To scroll it just set margin on container for example `margin-left: -300px;`

Working sample: http://jsfiddle.net/N9R2E/

Alternatively you may try this:

```
.categories-list {
    display: block;
    white-space: nowrap;
    margin-left: -300px;
    width: 10000px; /* long enough to fit all links */
}
a.category {
    display: block; 
    float:left;
    width: 280px; 
    padding: 10px;
    font-size: 30px; font-family: Cambria, 'Segoe UI', sans-serif; line-height: 35px;
    text-decoration: none; text-align: center; color: #42a6ce;
}
```

This uses `display:block` and `float:left` like in your attempt, but widths are fixed. To have all links in one line `categories-list` must be wider then all links together.

Working sample: http://jsfiddle.net/N9R2E/3/

Comment: I also thought about using negative margins. The only thing I think is wrong with your answer is that `white-space: nowrap` should be placed into `a.category` where `display: inline-block` is set, am I right?

Comment: @brick No. If you want to have text which doesn't wrap, you set `nowrap` on container holding this text. `inline-block` is treated as inline element in terms of arranging, so this is exacly what i wanted. Thanks  to that all links are in single line. Setting `white-space: nowrap;` on `a.category` would affect elements inside this element. Here is sample: http://jsfiddle.net/N9R2E/

Comment: I get it. That's true it keeps them together. The only thing I'm not sure is where those right margins on `a.category` come from. I believe it is the way the browser renders links.

Comment: They are not displayed in metrics panel though are visible.

Comment: I think this are spaces between sibling links. You may remove them or we must think of something else.

Comment: I've updated my answer with another solution, which doesn't have problem with white spaces.

Comment: Yep, that were whitespaces! Removed them)) Cool!

Answer (score 1):

If you don't mind using JS or buttons, this is one way to do it.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

var slider = $("#categoriese_list");                    
var leftProperty, newleftProperty;

// the click event handler for the right button                     
$("#right_button").click(function() { 

    // get value of current left property
    leftProperty = parseInt(slider.css("left"));

    // determine new value of left property
    if (leftProperty - 100 <= -900) {
        newLeftProperty = 0; }
    else {
        newLeftProperty = leftProperty - 100; }

    // use the animate function to change the left property
    slider.animate( {left: newLeftProperty}, 1000);

});  // end click

// the click event handler for the left button
$("#left_button").click(function() {

    // get value of current right property
    leftProperty = parseInt(slider.css("left"));

    // determine new value of left property
    if (leftProperty < 0) {
        newLeftProperty = leftProperty + 100;
    }
    else {
        newLeftProperty = -800;
    }

    // use the animate function to change the left property
    slider.animate( {left: newLeftProperty}, 1000);

   });  // end click        
}); // end ready
```

However, I would recommend making your categories list out of a `<ul>` to keep it more in line.

Answer (score 1):

What you're talking about is essentially a carousel or slider.  Rather than trying to code it from scratch I would just use one of the million jQuery plugins out there to build this.  I personally like [bxslider](http://bxslider.com/) a lot for things like this because it's responsive and very simple to implement.

Comment: Thanks for sharing a link to bxslider. I really like it! Of course I understand I'm reinventing the wheel. I just decided to try it by myself. Also third party plugins might be a huge pain when integrating them into Backbone application.

Comment: @brick You're headed in the right direction then. Basically you just need the overflow hidden "window" div with the absolutely positioned content beneath it.  Then just animate the position of the content div with javascript as needed.  You can also do it in pure CSS3 but it's more tricky and not nearly as widely compatible.